# Embed Macro in Document Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Is there a way to store custom macros inside a word document? I noticed that when I distribute a document with a macro I made that it arrives "macro-less" and therefore doesn't perform as expected.

I'd like to embed the needed macro inside the document to make it portable.

Perhaps this just isn't possible, but I'm hoping it is.

We use mostly office 2013

Comment: Hardly this happens that stored Macro can be found,,,, may possible it may produces some error.  Could you post the Macro you are trying to store with the file.

Comment: Did yu save the Macro with Template, Or Where it has been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when using VBA there are two places to store things.

Normal = "Global" to all local Docs, but also local to your machine

Project = "Only this Document" has access to these modules and they are portable AKA Embedded into Document! (Also, unavailable to all other doc's)

Note this image, the module and class are embedded inside the document vs global.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For macros recorded via the **Record Macro** button.

- And not assigned to either a *button* or *keyboard shortcut*:

  - In the [Store macro in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9v10.jpg) drop down list select the document itself.
- For macros recorded via **Record Macro** button and **Assign macro to Button** selected.

  - In the [Customize Quick Access Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzLLr.jpg) dropdown list select the document itself.
- For macros recorded via **Record Macro** button and **Assign macro to Keyboard** selected:

  - In the [Save changes in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1IDE.jpg) dropdown list select the document itself.

For macros created by the **Macros** button make sure in the [Macros in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaebK.jpg) dropdown list to select the document itself.

Comment: Note you can upload images to answers directly, a picture is worth a thousand words sometimes!

Comment: Absolutely, unfortunately users with lower rep cannot add images directly, feel free to edit my answer though it would be greatly appreciated.